# bilingual slides: beamer, comment package and non-ascii characters (umlauts, diacritical characters)

Tags: input-encodings

I'd like to generate beamer slides matching the main language of the target audience. The easiest way seems to facilitate the `comment` package and pack the individual slides into `includecomment`/`excludecomment` environments... (as suggested in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24223/multilingual-beamer-presentations-from-a-single-souce)).

However this breaks in various ways when non-ascii characters are involved depending on the location and character (and even document class) used, for example:

- `./comment.cut:2: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined`
- `./comment.cut:1: Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.`
- `./comment.cut:3: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \Uffffffffifnum (U+2E7) not set up for use with LaTeX.`

How can I make the following MWE work and what's the underlying issue?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\lvlang}{DE}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\iflvlangde}[2]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\lvlang}{DE}}{#1}{#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\iflvlangde{
  \usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
  \includecomment{DE}
  \excludecomment{EN}
}{
  \usepackage[main=english]{babel}
  \includecomment{EN}
  \excludecomment{DE}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{DE}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{mäh}
  föö
\end{frame}
\end{DE}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not just use a simple `\if \else \fi`? This is how I handle bilingual cases where some instances should use one language and some another. (I haven't tried with Beamer, though.) You shouldn't need `fragile` for the frame you show and, if that's forced by this approach, you really don't want to use it. At least, I wouldn't.

Comment: One downside is that it gets a bit more convoluted with more than two languages (which would be no problem for me). I need fragile all the time due to listings anyway and I think it slipped into the MWE because of that. However, I'd love to hear a better argument than 3+ language case.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As I have found out while writing up the question, the issue is the `comment` package or more specifically that it writes out expanded characters to its intermediate file. See the [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268229/23277) for more details.

The solution is to patch `comment`'s `WriteCommentLine` and `ThisComment` commands by adding the following after loading `comment`:

```
\long\def\WriteCommentLine#1{\immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}}
\let\ThisComment\WriteCommentLine
```

Thanks *egreg*!